# Chef Json values to ERB files

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, databags

How are values from data bag JSON files accessed from ERB files in Chef templates.

I have a data bag file named `chef-repo/data_bags/test.json` containing this data:

```
{
  "id": "test",
  "test": {
    "name": "doel"
  }
}
```

Within the `chef-repo/cookcooks/test/templates/default.erb` I am seeing that `<% @test.name %>` is accessed and is showing values accurately.

I'd like to understand where the instance variable `@test` is assigned the value of the data bag within Chef.

Answer (score 2):

The data bag gets read in a recipe. The extracted value is then passed to the template where it is then available in the ERB context. This can look something like this:

```
test = data_bag_item("my_data_bag", "test")

template "/path/to/target/file" do
  source "default.erb"
  variables :test => test
end
```

You can read more about variables in templates at the [template documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html).

As a final remark, you are missing some directories in your cookbook and chef repo. The erb file has to be at `chef-repo/cookcooks/test/templates/default/default.erb` (notce the added default directory). The data bag item should be in a directory named after the data bag (remember, there are many data bags, each containing many data bag items). Thus, in the code example above, your data bag should be in `chef-repo/data_bags/my_data_bag/test.json`.